# What does "cannot not do" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I came across this line from [Do Epic Shit](https://www.amazon.in/DO-EPIC-SHIT-Ankur-Warikoo/dp/9393986282), a self-help book which I'm reading currently and wondering what "cannot not do" mean in this context.

> The result of no efforts is nothing.
>
> The result of persistent efforts is a habit where you cannot not do the right thing.

Comment: "cannot" (or "can't") means "unable to".  "can not" means "able to choose not to".

Answer (score 1):

The sentence:

> The result of persistent efforts is a habit where you cannot not do the right thing.

has the same meaning as:

> The result of persistent efforts is a habit where you cannot **fail to do** the right thing.

That is, the author states that "doing the right thing" becomes automatic or inevitable if one makes a habit of "persistent efforts". The double use of "not" in the original is perhaps a bit awkward.